# when i am creating react file its giving me npx error

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
PS C:\Users\Anime\Desktop\Qspider\React Js> npx create-react-app react1
npx : The term 'npx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ npx create-react-app react1
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npx:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
```

Please help me to solve this problem i have downloaded node using nvs.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the command "npx" is not recognized. This is because the "npx" command is part of the Node Package Manager (npm), which needs to be installed separately.

To install npm, follow the instructions here:

https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm